# How to increase quality of the Video created from images using Microsoft AVI Library?

Tags: c++, video, msdn, avi

As part of the project requirement, I need to create an AVI video file from a sequence of PNG images. Currently I am using Microsoft AVI Library for the same. I am using the compression technique as 'M', 'S', 'V', 'C'.
Quality has been given as 10000 which is the maximum. But the quality of video is very bad. **How can i increase the video quality ? 
Should I use any other compression technique ?**

Below is the code:-

```
AVICOMPRESSOPTIONS CmpInfo; 
::ZeroMemory( &CmpInfo,sizeof( CmpInfo ));
CmpInfo.fccType = streamtypeVIDEO;
CmpInfo.fccHandler = mmioFOURCC( 'M', 'S', 'V', 'C' );
CmpInfo.dwKeyFrameEvery = 0;
CmpInfo.dwQuality = 10000;
CmpInfo.dwFlags = 8;
CmpInfo.dwBytesPerSecond = 0;
CmpInfo.lpFormat = 0;
CmpInfo.cbFormat = 0;
CmpInfo.lpParms = 0;
CmpInfo.cbParms = 0;
CmpInfo.dwInterleaveEvery = 0;        

HRESULT hr = ::AVIMakeCompressedStream( &m_pAviComprStream, m_pSourceStream, &CmpInfo, 0 );
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What you *should* do is to use ffmpeg.

Comment: We were using ffmpeg initially. But due to some license issues, we were forced to find an alternative. Hence we started using Microsoft AVI library.